# What's the meaning of * and & when applied to variable names?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, c++-faq

In C++, what is the difference between:

```
 void func(MyType&); // declaration

 //...
 MyType * ptr;

 func(*ptr); // compiler doesnt give error

 func(ptr); // compiler gives error i thought & represents memory address so 
            // this statement should correct as ptr is only a pointer
            // or address of some real var.
```

Comment: You should get a [book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c++-book-guide-and-list), which will teach you properly. (And better than we will.)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The ***unary prefix operator `&`***, when applied to an object, yields the ***address*** of the object: `&obj`.
The ***type modifier `&`***, when applied to a variable about to be declared, will modify the variable's type to be a ***reference type***: `int&`.

The same applies to `*`: When applied as a ***unary prefix operator*** to a pointer, it will ***dereference*** the pointer, yielding the object referred to: `*ptr`.
When used as a ***type modifier*** to a variable about to be declared, `*` will modify the type to be a ***pointer***: `int*`.

In a similar way, the ***type modifier `[]`*** applied to a variable that's being declared will modify the variable's type to an array, while the ***binary infix operator `[]`*** applied to an object of array type will access one of the array's sub-objects.

---

It's not helpful that ***type modifiers apply to the variable that is declared***, not to the type they are declared with. For example, this

```
int *p, **pp, i, a[10], &r = i;
```

defines an `int` pointer, a pointer to a pointer to an `int`, a vanilla `int`, an array of 10 `int`, and an `int` reference. (The latter is immediately initialized, because you cannot have an uninitialized reference.) Note that the ***type modifiers syntactically belong to the declared variable*** whose type they are modifying, not to the declared variable's type. Nevertheless, type modifiers (`*` and `&`) modify the *type* of the variable.
In the following case, however, with `p`, `i`, and `a` presumed to be variables that have already been declared

```
*pp = &i;
a[0] = i;
```

`*` and `&` are unary prefix operators dereferencing `pp` and yielding the address of `i`, while `[]` yields the first `int` object in the array `a`.

The fact that C and C++ don't care about the *whitespaces* around ***type modifiers*** and that this led to different camps when it comes to place them doesn't really make things easier.
Some people place the type modifiers close to the type. They argue that it modifies the type and so it should go there:

```
int* ptr;
```

The disadvantage is that this becomes confusing when declaring several objects. This

```
int* a, b;
```

defines `a` to be a pointer to `int`, but `b` to be an `int`. Which is why some people prefer to write

```
int *ptr;
int *a, *b;
```

I suggest to simply never declare multiple objects in the same statement. IMO that makes code easier to read. Also, it leaves you free to pick either convention.

---

To complicate things even further, besides the *type modifiers* and the *unary prefix operators* `&` and `*`, there are also the ***binary infix operators*** `&` and `*`, meaning "bitwise AND" and "multiplication". And to add insult to injury, in C++ you can ***[overload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading)*** both the *unary prefix* and the *binary infix* variants of these operators (and the *binary infix* `[]`) for user-defined types and be completely free as to their semantics.

Comment: how about using typedef to int* in case of line 2 example ?

Comment: @Kedar: Indeed, `typedef int* intptr; intptr a, b;` defines two `int*`. But my advice stays the same: One variable per declaration/definition.

Comment: Note that you can also dereference twice in a row (or more), e.g. `int a = 5; int* b = &a; int** c = &b; std::cout << **c;` which gets the value of `a` for `**c` and prints `5`.