# Operator how to use

Tags: c++, oop, operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the meaning of * and & when applied to variable names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350626/whats-the-meaning-of-and-when-applied-to-variable-names)

How to use & operator? herein i have an example:

```
Const  type& var
Const type & var
Const type &var
```

what does it mean?
Bests

Comment: I am not sure what you guys have smoked, but this is most certainly a totally real question. It's a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/q/3350626/140719, though.

Comment: @sbi: I second that,I am against Questions being closed as not a real Q just because they are pretty obvious to regular users of C++. For a beginner(inquisitive one) this is indeed an real question.
probably, It is a duplicate(as Sbi found out) but neither did any of the members who closed it,added a comment with the reason of closing it.

Comment: @Als: I flagged for a mod to fix that. I dunno whether any mod is around today, though.

Comment: You are confusing the meaning of `&`: in the present context, it is a modifier that designates a *reference* type. That's completely unrelated to many other meanings it can have (such as the "address-of" operator, the "bitwise-and" operator, or as part of the "logical-and" operator, or as a "user-defined `&`-operator").

Answer (score 3):

All of them mean the same. It makes no difference to the compiler which one you use.
For the compiler,
All three of those statements create a reference to a constant type.

It is a mere matter of style where to place the `&`. Use the style which your coding style/guidelines suggest you to use.

Comment: Thanks!! I've to ask to understand!!