# "&" meaning after variable type

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the differences between pointer variable and reference variable in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-pointer-variable-and-reference-variable-in-c)
>   [What's the meaning of * and & when applied to variable names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350626/whats-the-meaning-of-and-when-applied-to-variable-names)

Trying to understand meaning of "`&`" in this situation

```
void af(int& g)
{
    g++;
    cout<<g;
}
```

If you call this function and pass variable name - it will act the same like normal `void(int g)`. I know, when you write `&g` that means you are passing address of variable `g`. But what does it means in this sample?

Comment: You can find that information in a detailed, already answered form [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-pointer-variable-and-reference-variable-in-c).

Comment: act like normal? have you tried `af(v); af(v);`?

Comment: It's a reference, and if you don't know what it is I strongly recommend you to read a C++ book.

Comment: One link: http://codepad.org/1jTOscE8

Answer (score 37):

It means you're passing the variable by reference.

In fact, in a declaration of a type, it means reference, just like:

```
int x = 42;
int& y = x;
```

declares a reference to `x`, called `y`.

Answer (score 24):

The `&` means that the function accepts the *address* (or reference) to a variable, instead of the *value* of the variable.

For example, note the difference between this:

```
void af(int& g)
{
    g++;
    cout<<g;
}

int main()
{
    int g = 123;
    cout << g;
    af(g);
    cout << g;
    return 0;
}
```

And this (without the `&`):

```
void af(int g)
{
    g++;
    cout<<g;
}

int main()
{
    int g = 123;
    cout << g;
    af(g);
    cout << g;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "The & means that the function accepts the address"... ummm... no...

Comment: Just pointing out [void main](http://stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#void-main).

Comment: `void main()` is fine. Nothing wrong with this. Of course I assume that this is incomplete code (he misses "#include" too), so there will be a `namespace lulz { ... }` around his `void main`.

Comment: updated main to `int main` to make Chris happy ;)

And @LuchianGrigore: actually, yes, the function *does* accept the address.  If you use `printf("%x",&g);` inside and outside of of `af()`, you will find the values are different (at least when I compile with gcc...).  The compiler is actually making a copy of the memory address and passing that to the function; there IS another object on the stack, believe it or not (again, at least this is happening for me in gcc....)

Comment: That is, conceptually, it's passing a reference to the object instead of making a copy and passing the value but how it *actually* works with the gcc compiler is to make a copy of the memory address and pass it.

Comment: so you're saying you can call the function as `af(&g)`, right? Since `&g` is the address of `g`, and **you say** that `af` accepts the address of a variable?