# Why is my multiplication being treated like a pointer?

Tags: c++

Edit: simple mistake I looked over, and wasn't thinking. Ignore :)

My code brings up the error:

```
no match for 'operator*' in 'mapRows * width'
```

on the code

```
// get the current tile number
  int tileNumber = levelMap[mapRows*width + currentTile];
```

Declared at:

```
for (auto& mapRows : levelMap)
        for (auto& currentTile : mapRows)  //It loops through the rows, then goes through all the tiles in that column.
        {
```

and width at:

```
bool Map::load(const std::string& tileset, sf::Vector2u tileSize, unsigned int width, unsigned int height)
```

and levelMap at:

```
std::vector<std::vector<Tile>> levelMap;
```

Sorry, just a beginner!

Comment: Can we see the declaration of `mapRows` and `width`?

Comment: We want the type of mapRows, so we need to see the declaration of `levelMap` too. But it seems to be a collection so you might want to try `mapRows.size()*width`

Comment: Obviously, whatever `mapRows` refers to, does not have the binary multiplication operator overloaded. See [this FAQ answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3350710/140719) of mine to understand when `*` means dereferencing and when it means multiplication. (See [this entry](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4421719/140719) (see "Binary arithmetic operators") on how to overload operators.)

Comment: @Mixerman123 I have a suspicion that your problem is not just the error. Maybe try to describe what you tried to do since the access doesn't seem to make much sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mapRows` appears to be an `std::vector<Tile>` for which multiplication with an `int` doesn't make sense. That's what the error is telling you.

Comment: To be honest I'm not even sure how to correct this because I have no clue as to what you are trying to do with `operator*` there. Nothing related to `mapRows` or `levelMap` makes sense with `operator*`.

Comment: @sbi: In 2d game programming, it's pretty common to call the 2d grid of bitmap tiles on which the characters move a map.